# Unable to find the employee with second highest salary of department 'admin'(case-sensitive) using awk

Tags: linux

My intention is to find the employee with second highest salary from all the employees of department 'admin'(case-sensitive). Display the employee name with his/her department. If there are insufficient records, display relevant message.

```
sort -k4nr unix.txt | grep -e 'admin' | awk '{ if ((NR >= 2) && (FNR == 2)) {print $1,$2} else if (NR < 2) {print "No Sufficient Records in the file"}}'


Getting output like this:
No Sufficient Records in the file
Harry Manager

The contents of unix.txt file is as follows
Name Designation Department Salary
Sheetal Clerk Admin 12000
tarun peon sales 15000
Rahul HR aCCounts 20000
Deepak Clerk admin 23000
Ajay manager Admin 45000
amit manager ACCOUNTS 47000
varun manager sales 50000
satvik director purchase 80000
Raju Engineer admin 40000
Harry Manager admin 35000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you were close, but I think you don't need `grep` since you can "tell" `awk` to do the following action only if the third field is "admin", so we can use a variable, `n`, to store the number of "admin" records examined (numeric variables in awk defaults to 0), if the current is 2, print the record and exit. at the `END` if the number is still less than 2, print the message:

```
$ sort -k4nr unix.txt | awk '$3 == "admin" { n++; if (n == 2) { print $0; exit; } } END { if (n < 2) print "No Sufficient Records in the file" }'
Harry Manager admin 35000
$
```

here an example with no valid records:

```
$ printf "foo\nbar\nbaz" | sort -k4nr | awk '$3 == "admin" { n++; if (n == 2) { print $0; exit; } } END { if (n < 2) print "No Sufficient Records in the file" }'
No Sufficient Records in the file
$
```

and an example with just one "admin" record:

```
$ cat unix.txt
Name Designation Department Salary
Sheetal Clerk Admin 12000
tarun peon sales 15000
Rahul HR aCCounts 20000
Deepak Clerk admin 23000
Ajay manager Admin 45000
amit manager ACCOUNTS 47000
varun manager sales 50000
satvik director purchase 80000
$ sort -k4nr unix.txt | awk '$3 == "admin" { n++; if (n == 2) { print $0; exit; } } END { if (n < 2) print "No Sufficient Records in the file" }'
No Sufficient Records in the file
$
```